# Preventing Circular Dependencies with Exported Singleton Class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, circular-dependency

I have a question regarding a scenario I keep running into building HTML5 games  resulting in difficult to manage circular dependencies.

I understand completely why the circular dependency is occuring and where it is occurring. However, I can't seem to figure out a convenient way to get around it, so I assume my logic / approach is fundamentally flawed.

**Here's a little bit of context.**

I have a game that has a single point of entry (compiled with Webpack) called `Game.js`. I have a basic event manager that allows for two functions `on(key, callback)` and `fire(key, parameters)`.

*The event manager simply creates an object, sets the supplied key of `on` as a property with an array value populated with any `callback` functions registered to that key. When the `fire` method is called that property is retrieved and all of the fuctions defined in it's array value are invoked.*

**What I'm trying to do**

I want to be able to instance the event manager on `Game.js` and export an instance of `Game` that other classes can import and subsequently register callbacks to the `Game` instances event manager.

```
class Game {

    constructor() {
        this.events = new EventManager();

        window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize.bind(this));
    }

    resize(event) {
       if(window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight) {
          this.events.fire('orientation-change', 'vertical');
       } else {
          this.events.fire('orientation-change', 'horizontal');
       }
    }

}

export default new Game();
```

Then for example a `Button` class may need to respond to an orientation change event fired by the `Game`. Please note the above is simply an example of a circumstance in which the event manager may fire an event, but this condition could be anything.

```
import Game from '../core/Game';    

class Button {

    constructor() {
       Game.events.on('orientation-change', this.reorient.bind(this));
    }

    reorient() {
        // ...
    }

}

export default Button;
```

The above class is a UI component called Button that needs to know when the `orientation-change` event is fired, again please note this event could be *anything*.

**What's the problem?**

Nothing looks particularly wrong with the above, however, because `Game.js` is the entry point, at some point an instance of Button is created whether it be directly in `Game.js` or through another class which is subsequently instanced via `Game.js` which of course causes a circular dependency because even if not directly, `Game` imports `Button` and `Button` imports `Game`.

**What I've tried**

There are two main solutions that I have found that work (to some degree). The first being simply waiting for the export to be available using an interval check of the value of Game in the constructor of `Button`, like this:

```
import Game from '../core/Game';

class Button {

    constructor() {
        let check = setInterval(() => {
            if(Game !== undefined) {
                Game.events.on('orientation-change', this.reorient.bind(this));

                clearInterval(check);
            }
        }, 100);
    }

    reorient() {
        // ...
    }

}

export default Button;
```

This will typically resolve in a single iteration.

The second solution being to use dependency injection and pass reference of Game to Button when it's instanced, which again works great, but the prospect of having to repeatedly do this per class seems unintuitive. The interval check works fine too, but seems hacky.

I'm feel like I'm completely missing something and that the solution isn't a difficult as I'm making it.

Thanks for any help regarding this.

Comment: Don't export `new Game()`, just export `Game`. Add a static `getInstance` method that, when first called, creates a new `Game` and stores it. Subsequent calls get the stored instance. That's the basics of creating a Singleton that you should be able to find on the intarwebs anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the help @MikeMcCaughan! So, I did what you suggested and it works as expected for getting the instance, but the problem still lies in the fact that Button at some point has to be instanced either directly or indirectly by Game, right? Here's a *working* example: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-L4NbI1ThWuVAgDmuzpT

Comment: I don't see why you need to create an instance of `Button` in `Game`.

Comment: With it being the entry point of the application, without reference being created either directly or indirectly through that class, it's excluded by the bundle right? So, if for example I have a class called `UserInterface.js` that instances `Button`. Instancing `UserInterface` in the entry point of the application `Game` in this case would cause the same circular dependency would it not?